# I can't save an auth token sent from Django rest framework in my angular client side

Tags: python, django, angular, token

I prepared the backend api in Django and am able to login/out and send a token when login is successful, so my problem is i can't build an http interceptor that is able to read the token and save it in local storage

I have already tried some methods i found in the internet but with no success this is what i catch in the console

```
     token: "fd3e2c1f51d45066e291ad8209bdd7e7cb3b5398"
     __proto__: Object
```

Comment: Why didn't you include what you have tried in your post?

Comment: Because the methods i have tried were all related to more or less to Express server and it's form in sending tokens and i tried to make it suitable for my Django server but i couldn't

Comment: Is it a CSRFToken?

Comment: no it's an django rest framework authtoken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store the token in localStorage, ie:

```
login(user) {
    return this.httpClient.post<any>('/api-token-auth/', user).pipe(map(resp => {
      // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
      if (resp && resp.token) {
        // store jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
        localStorage.setItem('token', resp.token);
      }
      return resp;
    }));
}

logout() {
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! this was very helpfull